# get the number of seconds left for the sleep command to end in a shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sleep

I built a shell script that sleeps for a specified amount of minutes and shows notification when it is done.

```
TIME=$(zenity --scale --title="Next Session in (?) minutes")

sleep $TIME'm'

BEEP="/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga"
paplay $BEEP
notify-send "Next Session" "Press <Ctrl><Shift><s> to run the script again"
```

I prevented multiple instance of the program from executing using a file based approach at the beginning of the code. When a user wants to run the script while another instance is running, it shows a notification that the script is already running.

```
LOCKFILE=/tmp/lock.txt
if [ -e ${LOCKFILE} ] && kill -0 `cat ${LOCKFILE}`; then
    notify-send "Already Running" $SECONDS
    exit
fi

trap "rm -f ${LOCKFILE}; exit" INT TERM EXIT
echo $$ > ${LOCKFILE}
```

and finally remove the temporary file at the end of the script

```
rm -f ${LOCKFILE}
```

Now I want to add a text to the notification that tells how many seconds are left for the sleep command in my shell script to end. (changing the already running notification as follows)

```
notify-send "Already Running" $SECONDS
```

To implement the sleep command with my own controlled while loop would affect the overall performance of the computer. I think the sleep command is a better option as it optimizes the process by sending itself to a waiting state in the process queue.
Is there any way I can go around the problem?

Comment: Such Wow, so much text, too few code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the time when the script is supposed to end in the lock file.

```
if [ -e "$LOCKFILE" ]; then
    read pid endtime < "$LOCKFILE"
    if kill -0 "$pid"; then
        notify-send "Already running" $(($(date +%s) - $endtime))
        exit
    fi
fi

trap "rm -f ${LOCKFILE}" EXIT   # Use cascaded trap
trap 'exit 127' INT TERM

echo $$ $(($(date +%s) + (60 * $TIME))) >"$LOCKFILE"
```

There is a race condition here; if two scripts are started at almost the same time, the first could be inside the `if` but before the `echo` when the second starts.  If you really need to prevent that, use a lock directory instead of a file -- directory creation is atomic, and either succeeds or fails at just a single point in time (but then you'll need to clean out the stale directory in the mystery scenario where the directory exists but is not owned by a file -- maybe after a careless OOM killer or something).

Comment: Incidentally, with the `EXIT` trap, there is no need to explicitly remove the lock file at the end of the script.

Comment: Nice one. works perfect. One modification though, the notify-send command cannot accept a negative number as the second argument it thinks as though a command line option is provided: so a little change to the fourth line in your code:
`notify-send "Already running" "$(($endtime - $(date +%s))) seconds remaining"`

Comment: Then `-13 seconds remaining` is not a valid option name either.  Perhaps change it to `"Seconds remaining: $(($endtime - $(date +%s)))"`... although if the result is negative, I suppose it ought to have finished already.

Comment: or just put the result of the difference in a variable and insert it into the string as:
`remaining=$(($endtime - $(date +%s)));
notify-send "Already running" "$remaining seconds remaining"`

Comment: That still fails if `$remaining` begins with a dash, so it doesn't help.

Comment: Yes that's right. I don't understand however, why you wanted to use cascade trap instead of putting them in one line?

Answer (score 0):

I think Triplee has a fine answer, another way to handle it that can be applied to any running process that may block is to `bg` the process briefly to grab and save the assigned pid `$!` to a file then `fg` the process back.

From there you can do the math and get the seconds via `ps`:

```
TIME=$(zenity --scale --title="Next Session in (?) minutes")

SLEEP_PID_FILE="/tmp/__session_ui_sleep_pid__" 
sleep $TIME'm' &
echo $! >> "${SLEEP_PID_FILE}" 
fg 

BEEP="/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga"
paplay $BEEP
notify-send "Next Session" "Press <Ctrl><Shift><s> to run the script again"
```

Then afterward you can find the current elapsed time with something like:
 
`notify-send "Already running for $(($(date +%s)-$(date -d"$(ps -o lstart= -p$(< "${SLEEP_PID_FILE}"))" +%s))) seconds..."`